# "With the public"—mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> In recent times, matters of consent in relation to medical treatment have achieved a high profile **with the public.**

What's the meaning of **with the public** ?

I think **with the public** mean- in the case of/concerning public

Comment: It just means the writer thinks that a high proportion of *people in general* ("the public") are now interested in / concerned about "issues of consent" in relation to medical treatment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so can I say **In recent times,high proportion of people in general are aware about the issue of necessity of consent in relation to medical treatment.**

Comment: You *must* include the article *(**a** high proportion)*, but other than that, your sentence is syntactically valid, and would be understood. It's not remotely idiomatic, though, so no native speaker would ever actually say it. Note that ***have achieved a high profile*** in your cited text is a construction typically used by "influencers" (newspaper columnists, bloggers,...). That's why I said ***the writer thinks*** above - in reality, it's more *people who work in mainstream media* who are concerned (they just *think* their readers care as much as they do).

Comment: (So far as I'm aware, during the Covid crisis, there was almost no mainstream media coverage about whether people at no significant risk themselves should be forced to radically change their lifestyles or accept inadequately tested vaccines. That doesn't mean *people in general* weren't concerned - just that mainstream media only wanted to report on public figures circumventing lockdown restrictions at the time.)

Comment: I’d explain it as “from the point of view of,” or “as seen by.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a "with"-phrase modifies "profile", it indicates the context of that profile. In this case, it means that many among public are aware of medical consent.

Without that "with"-phrase, the sentence would mean roughly the same thing since the public is the default context for having a profile. They're normally used to indicate specific groups:

> Medical consent has a high profile with Western Europeans.

This suggests that other places in the world don't have as much expectation of medical consent as Western Europeans do.